# How to update Microsoft Office?

Tags: lumia-520, app-update, word

I have Lumia 520 with updated OS of 8.1 (8.10.12393.890 to be more precise) but when I open my documents {.rtf and.doc format) I can just read them and I am unable to edit those documents, an error message appears saying

> unsupported content. This version of Word doesn't support some
>   of the contents in this document. You won't be able to make any changes

I think updating Word will get it done, but how to do so?

Comment: You can't update Word. It's built into the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation for Word Mobile:

> Word Mobile doesn't support all the features in Microsoft Word 2010 or later. If a document has content that's not supported, you can still open the document on your phone. The unsupported content won't be displayed though, and you might not be able to edit the document.

The only thing you can do to edit the document is to remove or change the parts of the document that Word Mobile doesn't support. Unfortunately I can't find a comprehensive list of features supported by Word Mobile, but if you compare how the document looks on your phone and on a PC, you should be able to figure out which parts of the document look different or are missing altogether.

For more information, see [Use Word Mobile for Windows Phone](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/use-word-mobile-for-windows-phone-HA103953541.aspx).